# Problem with changing date to format DMMYYYY in Python

Tags: python, windows, datetime, date-formatting

I have a problem with changing date format to e.g. 9November2021 but not 09November2021.

```
d = date(2021, 11, 9)
```

I tried to do it this way: `d.strftime('%-d%B%Y')` but although it seems to be working on my personal laptop with MacOS, when I try to run it on my work laptop with Windows I get a **ValueError: Invalid format string.**

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `#` on Windows instead of `-`

so instead of `d.strftime('%-d%B%Y')`
Try this `d.strftime('%#d%B%Y')`

Comment: Thank you! That really helped.

Comment: @maciejrum consider accepting an answer if it helped - but note you're *not* obligated to do so. see more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

This is a great web page for all your formatting needs: https://strftime.org

I believe instead of a "-", you will want to use a "#" on Windows.  If you are still having issues, another solution is suggested here: https://github.com/evennia/evennia/issues/1881 -- they suggest using "{dtobj.day}" instead of "-d".

Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Thank you so much!